# Why Xamarin not throwing Exception in another thread?

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, exception, xamarin

I'm developing mobile apps with Xamarin Framework.
Today I tried to throw exception in another thread, like this:

```
public class ExceptionInAnotherThread
{
    public void Throw()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        });
    }
}
```

And run this code in MainActivity.OnCreate on Android, MainViewController.ViewDidLoad on iOS. There was no exception, app run normally. But in Console Application (Windows) exception calls properly. Is there any solutions to throw exceptions in another threads?

Regards, Max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await the Task. Change your code to be:

```
public class ExceptionInAnotherThread
{
    public async void Throw()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        });
    }
}
```